# Why free() release data but save next_node value?

Tags: c, list, free

I was training with lists and from some point I start wonder how exactly work free() function. I was think that this will clear either data and next_node values in struct first_node (look at code), but instead only data values was destroy and next_node still point to next position on my list. Why?

```
struct Data
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct Node
{
    struct Data* data;
    struct Node* next_node;
};

struct List
{
    struct Node* first_node;
};

void init(struct List* list)
{
    list->first_node = NULL;
}
…
struct Data* remove_first_element_from_list(struct List* list)
{
    if (list->first_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("The list is empty!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    struct Data *pointer;
    pointer = list->first_node->data;
    free(list->first_node);
    list->first_node = list->first_node->next_node;
    return pointer;
}
```

Thanks for any explaination.

Comment: Because `free` is allowed to do whatever it wants with the thing you just freed. In this case, your platform's particular implementation of `free` didn't need to overwrite` next_node`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have *undefined behavior* when you do

```
list->first_node = list->first_node->next_node
```

The UB is because `list->first_node` no longer points to allocated memory.

However, nothing says that when you call `free` the data has to be cleared or otherwise modified. All it does is tell the operating system that the memory is once again available for someone to allocate. That's why you can still use the pointer, and that's one of the things with UB, the behavior is *undefined*, and can sometimes *seem* to work when in reality it's a very serious problem.

Comment: Minor nitpick: for such small allocations the OS is rarely involved - any self-respecting allocator would manage the "small stuff" by itself, without trapping in kernel.

Answer (score 1):

`free` just releases the memory to allow it to be used again (e.g. in another call to `malloc`).

It does not clear the memory. So if you use it after the free call you **might** get the same value.

Using the memory after it has been freed, as you have done in the line after the call to `free` is **"undefined behaviour"** and may work sometimes, and not work sometimes - the results can vary each time you run the program. So - **don't do it!**

Answer (score 0):

`Free` basically releases memory that a pointer points to. In the list you have two pointers pointing to different locations and you have freed the memory pointed by data and not the memory pointed by next_node, Therefore that memory is still within your reach.

Answer (score 0):

`free` doesn't need to erase anything - that would be a waste of time -, it just marks the block of memory you gave back as "free to be recycled", adding it back to some free blocks list that it will examine at the next `malloc`. The fact that one or two members of the memory block has been modified is just an implementation detail - and you shouldn't peek into freed blocks anyway, as the allocator is free to unmap their memory, thus giving you a segfault (more in general, looking at the content of deallocated memory is "undefined behavior", i.e. anything can happen).